# Determine if a node exists in a Boost binomial_heap

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to determine if an element exists in a boost::heap::binomial_heap because I need  to know if I should call update() (if the node already exists) or push() (if the node does not exist). Some queues provide a push_or_update() function for exactly this purpose. The only thing I could figure out to do is keep a property map with the same index type as the nodes in the queue and value_type 'handle_t'. Then I can lookup in the map if the item has a valid handle so that I can push if it does not, or update if it does.

Is there a better way to do this?

[Here is the doc for reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/heap/binomial_heap.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something a binomial heap is supposed to do.

A usual way to solve your problem would be: use a hash map (or other data structure you like) to store a mapping between values and `handle`s. You can then query the hash map for the handle. If it exists, this handle will let you modify the value in the heap. If it doesn't exist, you can just add a new value to the heap (of course, and a new mapping in the hash map)

Another way to solve the problem is to use a tree set/map, which is easier and may be more efficient than the solution I described above, depending on the actual use case.